# Issues installing MotionEye on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, pycurl

I installed all the required programs, but when I try to install MotionEye (sudo pip install motioneye) I get the following error:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EI7W87/pycurl
```

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log

the full log I got:

```
Collecting motioneye
  Using cached motioneye-0.35.tar.gz
Collecting tornado>=3.1 (from motioneye)
  Using cached tornado-4.4.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from motioneye)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from motioneye)
Collecting pycurl (from motioneye)
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-MEnLpy/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in <module>
        ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-MEnLpy/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-MEnLpy/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-MEnLpy/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-MEnLpy/pycurl/
```

I have tried updating pip:

```
sudo pi install -U pip
```

And:

```
 sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

and some other things that I forgot.

I am running Raspbian 8: jessie

Not sure if this helps, here are the other programs I run on my pi: samba, miniDLNA, no-ip DUC and openhab.

Personally I was thinking it was an issue with pycurl so I tried to reinstall it, but without succes:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip install pycurl
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4w1sfS/pycurl/setup.py", line 823, in <module>
        ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4w1sfS/pycurl/setup.py", line 497, in get_extension
        ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4w1sfS/pycurl/setup.py", line 71, in __init__
        self.configure()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-4w1sfS/pycurl/setup.py", line 107, in configure_unix
        raise ConfigurationError(msg)
    __main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4w1sfS/pycurl/
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 minidlna : Depends: libavformat56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
 motion : Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed or
                   libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.7) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libpq5 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libswscale3 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it!
It was indeed a problem with pycurl. I fixed the error that I got when running `sudo apt-get install python-pycurl`
I solved it with:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After that I was able to install pycurl using:

```
apt-get install python-pycurl
```

And afterwards motioneye install worked like a charm!